# Filter specific table rows in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting some data from the API and showing them as a table.

```
{
    name: 'firstName',
    cellProps: { numeric: false },
    header: 'First',
}, {
    name: 'lastName',
    cellProps: { numeric: false },
    header: 'Last',
}, {
    name: 'total',
    header: 'Total',

}, {
    name: 'country',
    cellProps: { numeric: false },
    header: 'Country',
},
```

Then I'm calculating the overall total value using reduce:

```
const dailytotal = dailySales.reduce((acc, { total }) => acc + total, 0);
```

now I'm trying to calculate overall total values based on the country to the totals for each country.

```
const CAfilter = dailySales.filter( { country } => {country} === 'CA');
const CAtotal = CAfilter.reduce((acc, { total }) => acc + total, 0);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (49:9)

  47 |             country;
  48 |         }
> 49 |          === 'CA';
     |          ^
  50 |         ;
  51 |         const CAtotal = CAfilter.reduce((acc, { total }) => acc + total, 0);
```

Comment: Is `country` a property of the object, I can't see `country` as property name? Also, if you are destructuring object at `filter` then it will be `.filter(({country}) => ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const CAfilter = dailySales.filter( ({ country }) => country === 'CA');`

You can only omit the parenthesis of an arrow function if it has a single argument.  Object destructuring doesn't count as a single argument.

You also had then declared a new object of, essentially:

```
{country: country}
```

when all you really wanted was the individual value of `country`.

Answer (score 1):

In your filter function you aren't returning anything, you can do

```
const CAfilter = dailySales.filter( ({ country }) => country.name === 'CA');
```